# Filter sum with an OR statement?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter

=SUM(H33:H41)+SUM(I33:I41)**+ FILTER(Transactions!F:F,Transactions!C:C="Deposit")**

The snippet above works fine, but I am getting errors when I try to add a filter for "Withdrawal".

=SUM(H33:H41)+SUM(I33:I41)**+FILTER(Transactions!F:F,Transactions!C:C="Deposit")+FILTER(Transactions!F:F,Transactions!C:C="Withdrawal")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(H33:I41)+FILTER(Transactions!F:F, REGEXMATCH(Transactions!C:C, "Deposit|Withdrawal"))
```